# ERROR 403 Google plus friend list access

Tags: jquery, google-plus, google-oauth, google-api-js-client

I am using Google plus Oauth in client side in a web application . I have registered and could get userinformation using the api, But When I tried to get the friend list using the following get operation, I am getting a 403 error

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/{userid}/people/{collection}
```

I have set the `userid` and `collection`, but unfortunately I got this error

```
{
 "error": {`enter code here`
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured"
 }
}
```

**Note**: I have included `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login` to the scope also.

Could somebody help me please, Thanks in advance

Comment: Include the JavaScript code that you are using to make the requests. I believe you aren't using the API methods but are instead manually assembling the requests to those end points, which is going to give you problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally solved it myself, I am posting this answer in order to help other people who have got the same error
You have to append the accesstoken in the end

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/{userid}/people/{collection}?access_token={accesstoken}
```

or you could use `me` instead `{userid}`

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/people/{collection}?access_token={accesstoken}
```

both works fine.
Thank you

Comment: If you are using the client libraries properly, you do not need to append the access tokens. When you using the client libraries to format the requests that is handled automatically. I believe you've left out important parts of your code that would show issues with how it is assembled.